# How to Convert Java Web-application into Desktop (.exe) application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have developed a web-application based on spring hibernate jsp, is it possiable that i can convert this web-application  into desktop application or .exe file or is there any other way of converting .war file to .exe file

Comment: I guess the downvoter (who was not me) wanted to express that your question shows some lack in effort. What have you tried / researched so far? Why weren't the results of your research satisfying to you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can make a .exe of your sprid web-application. I suggest you create a small awt/swing wrapper and use the web-view to display the web-application in the simple broswer. You can then package it as jar and run.

Not tried anytime but should help.

Answer (score 0):

If I am know right, that you want to convert your web into desktop app (.exe)
I have created the project that can convert web to exe via python
https://github.com/HoangQuanGITHUB/web2exe
Hope this useful!